# Should I not leave my company when it is making progress?

Tags: india, startup

I am working in a SAAS startup, which is around 4 years old. Most of the people there have **no interest** in the **quality of work**, rather they want more projects (more money in fact). Also, the pay that I get, is way below the average market rates. The learning curve is reducing, and there are not many skill sets. Even the general manager does not care much about new technology.(We sometimes answer to the general manager about the progress). As an example, when blockchain technology was hyped during the lockdown, all he said to me was that it was nothing and very easy, and people are making a useless fuss about it. I am also paid for like 10 out of 12 months of salary, and until now, most of the money came from one huge project.

But now, there are a few more projects which have come up, and a few more where the company is almost confident to close the deal with.  I was recently asked to learn a new skillset, but again there is no certainty that the project will be bagged by us. Also, the company is willing to do all the work, either through unpaid/low paid internships, or by low paid employees. Even the company sometimes advices clients to do a project using a certain skillset, which have barely any market value (which is mostly outdated), because the labour will be cheap.

Should I search for a new job, or wait here in the hope of a better future?

Comment: Note the purpose of a business isn't to do quality work, use new technology, or enhance the skillsets of employees. It's to make money. Sometimes those things are in alignment.

Comment: Try to imagine how you'll feel in, say, 3 years if you stay where you are. Then try to imagine how you'll feel in 3 years if you've moved to a different job. Which is better? — Of course, that's impossible to answer, because you can't know what that different job would be like. (Depending how optimistic and/or risk-averse you are, you may be imagining unrealistically great or unrealistically awful things for it.) But it can still be a helpful exercise. And if changing jobs seems _likely_ to be the better option, then you know what to do!

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yes it is. If the coding standards are not close to industry standards, then the maintainance will be costly. That aside, the people who provide the support will face terrible nightmares. Also, codes should also be scalable, which is mostly overlooked by most of our seniors.

Comment: @Asish Those are all things that help achieve the goal to make money. They are not the goal in their own right.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Yes, but the whole purpose of our company is to advice clients on how to enhance their business. It's somewhat like, "You deal with the business and customers, let us handle your digital part". If the quality of coding is not upto mark, or if a technology which is getting outdated is used, the company will struggle to find support. Example- there arent many people left who have experience on .Net Framework, so the support will de either costly or delayed

Comment: @Asish If your company is struggling to find support, than that is a problem. But it looks like a problem that the company is willing to wear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get paid below the average market rate *and* only get paid 10 out of 12 months? Why are you even there? What do you hope will "improve"? To what point, improve to the point where they pay you a fair salary?

> Should I search for a new job?

Sure. Why would you *not* do that? It is not mandatory to *take* any of the jobs you find during your search. Search and if something better comes up, take it. If it turns out that right now in the middle of the pandemic there is nothing better... no harm no foul.